# Can I use this scenario to handle protected routes in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use session-storage to save login data like token etc.

Is it best practice to use this scenario for redirecting un-authorized users?

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (token === null) {
      navigate('/users/login');
    }
}, []);
```

because I've 2 kind of pages in app.

some pages should load with token and some not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather implement a component that does this check for you, as suggested [here](https://dev.to/iamandrewluca/private-route-in-react-router-v6-lg5), so you don't have to check for the token in every component:

```
// In case authentication is required, wrap the component to be rendered inside PrivateRoute
<Route
    path="/protectedPage"
    element={
      <PrivateRoute>
         <ProtectedPage/>
      </PrivateRoute>
    }
/>
// In case no authentication is required, just render the element as it is
<Route
    path="/unprotectedPage"
    element={
       <UnprotectedPage/>
    }
/>
// In case you don't want to show the page to an authenticated user
<Route
    path="/protectedPage"
    element={
      <PrivateRoute redirectIfAlreadyAuthenticated={true}>
         <Login/>
      </PrivateRoute>
    }
/>

function PrivateRoute({ children, redirectIfAlreadyAuthenticated=false }) {
  if(redirectIfAlreadyAuthenticated)
    return token? <Navigate to="/" /> : children;
  else
    return token? children : <Navigate to="/users/login" />;
}
```

Comment: thank you, but there is an issue... dashboard page needs Authenticate, but login and register don't need and I should redirect user in these to dashboard pages after login

Comment: If you don't need an authentication, then it is likely like the case unprotectedPage that I just showed you, isn't it ?

Comment: I see, but we shouldn't show register or login page to Authenticated users... I mean, with your solution we will show them those pages

Comment: I updated the answer. Does it seems better? You can adapt the verification logic to your specific needs, here it is just an example.  I used a prop redirectIfAlreadyAuthenticated, but you could also create an other component that does this check also